# Filtering data in cfselect based on another cfselect

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

In a ColdFusion application I'm working on, the user will see two cfselects, one with a list of regions and one with a list of centers. Each region has it's own set of centers. When the user clicks a region in the first cfselect, it should populate the second one with a list of centers.

My plan is to have a full list of centers in the list, and make them visible when their corresponding region is selected. Is there an easy way to do this? I'm very new to ColdFusion so I'm struggling. Here is the code for the two cfselects I have:

```
<td>
        <cfset SelectionListWidthAndHeight =  "width:375px; height:" & min(130, ((REGIONS.RecordCount-1) * 13)) & "px;">
        <cfselect           name            = "Select_Region_ID"
                            query           = "REGIONS"
                            queryposition   = "below"
                            value           = "REGION_ID"
                            display         = "Region"
                            selected        = "0" 
                            size            = "10"
                            style           = #SelectionListWidthAndHeight#
                            required        = "yes"
                            message         = "You must specify a center."
                            onchange        =  "">
                            <option value="All">All regions and centers</option>



        </cfselect>                 
    </td>

<td>
        <cfset SelectionListWidthAndHeight =  "width:375px; height:" & min(130, ((CENTERS.RecordCount-1) * 13)) & "px;">
        <cfselect           name            = "Select_Center_ID"
                            query           = "CENTERS"
                            queryposition   = "below"
                            value           = "CENTER_ID"
                            display         = "Center"
                            selected        = "0" 
                            size            = "10"
                            style           = #SelectionListWidthAndHeight#
                            required        = "yes"
                            message         = "You must specify a center."

                            >
                            <option value="All">All centers in region</option>

        </cfselect>
    </td>
```

The list of regions and centers are retrieved using cfstoredprocs:

```
<cfstoredproc procedure="spGetAllRegions" datasource="APD">
    <cfprocresult name="REGIONS" resultset="1">
</cfstoredproc>

<cfstoredproc procedure="spGetAllCenters" datasource="APD">
    <cfprocresult name="CENTERS" resultset="1">
</cfstoredproc>
```

CFC Code so far:

```
<cfcomponent output="false">
<cfset variables.dsn = "APD">

<cffunction name="getregions" access="remote" returntype="query">
    <cfset var getData = "">

    <cfquery name="getData" datasource="#variables.dsn#"> 
        SELECT DISTINCT REGION_ID FROM Regions
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn getData />
</cffunction>
```

Comment: **Updated** I noticed "bind:cfc..." was removed. If you actually were to use `cfselect`.. you're right in thinking you'd need to use "bind" with a cfcomponent. That said... the general recommendation nowadays is to [avoid cfselect (and other UI components)](https://github.com/cfjedimaster/ColdFusion-UI-the-Right-Way) because they underlying libs are outdated and hard to customize. Ultimately that tag is just a wrapper around other javascript libraries, so may as well DIY with jQuery. 1) Can you post your CFC code? 2) Are you familiar with JavaScript?

Comment: Yeah I had the bind attribute set as I was trying some solutions others posted online, but I removed it because I wanted to post the code as it was before I started working on this problem. My CFC code is pretty much nonexistant, I started writing one while following along with somebody else's solution but I didn't get very far. I'll add it in to my original post though. I'm pretty familiar with JavaScript, not a master by any means but knowledgeable enough to Google what I need to know.

Comment: I subscribe to the school of thought that using the ColdFusion baked in javascript cfform and UI elements is generally a bad idea. The problem you're describing could easily be implemented with jquery in a few minutes, as is the case with most things that ColdFusion obfuscates using their UI tags and injected javascript. Once you have full control over your JS and UI elements, the case for using ColdFusion UI elements is extremely weak, especially when you need to customize them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Too long for comments)

Well, there's really 2 parts to it: server side code (CF) and client side (Javascript/Ajax). A full example is a little long for a single S.O. thread. If it were me, I'd focus on writing the CF code 1st. Get the `<cfcomponent>` to return the data you want - in the format you want. After it's up and working, move on to the client side code.

As far as the ColdFusion code, your current CFC looks good. The only thing I'd change is have the functions return an array of structures instead of a "query" object. CF defaults to a wonky format when serializing query objects. Better to build your own structures IMO.

```
<cffunction name="getRegions" access="remote" returntype="array">

    <cfquery name="local.getData" datasource="#variables.dsn#"> 
        SELECT Region_Id, Region
        FROM   Regions
        ORDER BY Region
    </cfquery>

    <!--- convert each record into structure and append to array --->
    <cfset local.results = []>
    <cfloop query="local.getData">
       <cfset arrayAppend(local.results, {"value": region_id, "label": region})>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn local.results />
</cffunction>
```

To see what data the ajax call will receive, load it in your browser and test the remote function:

`http://localhost/YourComponent.cfc?method=getRegions&returnformat=json`

You can create a similar function to return the centers associated with a specific region id. The only difference is it requires a region id as an argument:

```
<cffunction name="getCenters" access="remote" returntype="array">
    <cfargument name="region_id" type="numeric" required="true">

    <cfquery name="local.getData" datasource="#variables.dsn#"> 
        SELECT Center_Id, Center
        FROM   Centers
        WHERE  Region_Id = <cfqueryparam value="#arguments.region_id#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
        ORDER BY Center
    </cfquery>
    <!--- convert each record into structure and append to array --->
    <cfset local.results = []>
    <cfloop query="local.getData">
        <cfset arrayAppend(local.results, {"value": center_id, "label": center})>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn local.results>
</cffunction>
```

Testing is similar, you just need to supply a region id as a url parameter:

`http://localhost/YourComponent.cfc?method=getCenters&returnformat=json&region_id=123`

Comment: **Edit** Fixed typos.  Btw, though the example uses cfquery, there's no reason you can't use cfstoredproc instead.

Comment: Awesome thanks so much for the help, that method of testing the functions will be really helpful for me. I was successful in retrieving the regions from the database, but for getting centers by region it's telling me that there is an attribute tag validation error for cfloop (local.getData is invalid).

Comment: Nevermind I just realized I had the array declaration and cfloop inside the cfquery. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad it helped! I don't know if you're new to CF, but since you're familiar with JS - if you prefer script syntax over tags (cfml), take a look at [cfscript](https://cfdocs.org/script).  The example used tags only because that's what's in the OP.

Comment: I'll definitely check that out, I'm very new to CF and I'm not a huge fan of the tags. I'm trying to bind my first cfselect to getRegions, but ColdFusion tells that "getRegions was not found on the CFC Functions/queryoptions". It seems like it's finding the CFC where getRegions is defined but can't find the function, do you have any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: **Update** Oh! Sorry, I thought you were going with jQuery.  You'll need different code for cfselect.  Though I wouldn't recommend using it (in time you'll find it's a headache ;-) if you still want to try it out give me a sec to test an example.. been so long since I've used it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180553/discussion-between-ageax-and-hairyduck).

Comment: I probably should try to use jQuery, even just to get familiar with it. Cfselect (and cfAlmostEverythingElse) seems to be a bit of a headache, but I hopefully won't have to work on this app for too much longer. Don't feel obligated to come up with an example for cfselect, you've helped me a bunch already.

Comment: Well, ignoring the UI stuff (which was a silly idea IMO) most things in CF to be simpler and usually 1/3 of the code of other languages ;-) Anyway, the reason I asked if you tested the component is because if there's a syntax error it won't compile .. and that could be why your cfselect isn't working. So did you verify it works from the browser? :)